# Swing - get main window class instance from button class

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent

I need to run a method (lets call it `SampleMethod`) in a panel class upon the click on specific button. As panels are added to some sort of list in the main window class instance, I just made it public, and want to access it in `mouseClicked` event of the button.
So, how do I get the main window instance, so I could get that panel list, get the specific panel and run `SampleMethod` with this instance?

Comment: do you want to determine parent, in this case JFrame/JDialog/JWindow ???

Comment: Well, actually yes. I found a ComponentFactory class in that project, though, which does all the dirty job. I'll answer the question ASA I get the complete understanding of it.

Comment: create all JFrame/JDialog/JWindow once time, re_use that for another action(s)

Comment: _lets call it SampleMethod_ - no, it would be sampleMethod :-) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @kleopatra I find it forgivable since this is no production application. I'm a C# programmer, and I'm more interested in architectural challenges of this task, than in some idiotic differences between language conventions.

Comment: if you want to successfully communicate with swing natives, use their language instead of yours ;-)

Comment: @Nordvind can you check my answer? singleton pattern will enable you to use main window instance.

Comment: Well, I'll check it, but I've managed to solve the problem, I'll add the own answer as I have time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As panels are added to some sort of list in the main window class
>   instance...

The main window class instance? It seems you have only one instance of your main window which may extend `JFrame` or `JPanel` or `JDialog` etc. Anyway, you can use **Singleton** design pattern in your application to get and use the same instance (in your case the same main instance) anywhere in your code. In Singleton pattern, the constructor of the class that we apply the pattern is **private**, so you cannot make instances of it. However this class has also its **single static instance** which can be referenced via getter method and used anywere in your code. Take a look at Singleton examples on the web and you will be able to make a call like

`YourJFrame.getInstance().getPanels(10).sampleMethod()`;

in your nested classes and methods, in your case `mouseClicked()`.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) as a way to expose the desired functionality. The common use is to let buttons and menus share the same handler, but one `Action` can *forward* an event to another, as shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel) for buttons and keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

[Window w = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(Component c);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent%28java.awt.Component%29)

Answer (score 0):

What trashgod said. Use the ActionListener class and the buttons addActionListener() instead since you only need to know if the button was pressed or not.